# Search Twitter for tweets without links, media, or interactions?

Tags: twitter

I'm looking for a way to purge a few of my Twitter accounts without deleting all of their tweets. I want to be able to find every tweet that isn't linking to someone or doesn't have any interactions (likes, retweets, replies, etc.) but can't seem to find a way to filter those in a timely manner.

Comment: Sounds rather like something that would require using the API, but then it would be out-of-scope here.